# SQL Statement with Left Joins, Where Clause, and a Sum()?

Tags: sql, sum, left-join, where-clause

I'm really struggling with the below SQL.  I have tried so many different things, and I can't get any of them to work.

What I basically need to do is LEFT OUTER JOIN this working SQL statement:

```
SELECT   "TABLE1"."Sheet Number",
         "TABLE1"."ID Number",
         "TABLE1"."Identification",
         "TABLE1"."Job Date",
         "TABLE1"."p2c",
         "TABLE2"."Range",
         "TABLE1"."bcr",
         "TABLE1"."Dataset ID",
         "TABLE1"."ACC",
         "TABLE1"."GNC",
         "TABLE1"."Year",
         "TABLE1"."Period",
         "TABLE1"."Week",
         "TABLE1"."Job_ID"
FROM     "DATABASE"."dbo"."TABLE2" "TABLE2" LEFT OUTER JOIN "DATABASE"."dbo"."TABLE1" "TABLE1"
         ON (((("TABLE2"."Contract"="TABLE1"."GNC")
         AND ("TABLE2"."FromPeriod"="TABLE1"."Period"))
         AND ("TABLE2"."FromWeek"="TABLE1"."Week"))
         AND ("TABLE2"."FromYear"="TABLE1"."Year"))
WHERE    "TABLE1"."ACC"='ACCOUNT57' 
         AND "TABLE1"."Dataset ID"=5 
         AND "TABLE1"."bcr"=1 
         AND "TABLE2"."Range"='Week'
ORDER BY "TABLE1"."Sheet Number"
```

with this one:

```
SELECT  "SALES"."JobId",
        "SALES"."Total",
        SUM("SALES"."Total") AS JOBTOTAL
FROM   "DATABASE"."dbo"."SALES" "SALES"
GROUP BY "SALES"."JobId"
ON "SALES"."JobId"="TABLE1"."Job_ID"
```

But the other joins are causing me a great deal of confusion/frustration when trying to implement solutions I've found online.  I've read that it may be the WHERE and GROUP BY statements not playing nice??

But I can't seem to get any solution I find online to work. One solution I tried looked like it just wrapped the SQL statement with the SUM() and GROUP BY (my bottom statement) inside brackets and joined that?

Is anyone out there able to help?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The easiest was is actually wrapping the SUM Select in a Derived Table and then Left Join to it. And check if the result of the 1st query is what you expect, it's an Inner join instead of Left.

Comment: you are not using any columns from table 2 are you trying to limit the results ot table 1 by table 2?

Comment: Yes table 2  is only used to limit the results of table 1 - it should have an inner join tbh but i was messing around trying to get this to work and started changing anything and everything. Also it was a derived table i tried to implement but i just couldn't get it working...

Comment: see my answer then, dnoeth has a point that some times it would be easier to wrap your SUM() query in a derived table but that is actually less readable for intent and may not optimize the same as just writing the query using joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    t1.Sheet Number,
    t1.ID Number,
    t1.Identification,
    t1."Job Date",
    t1.p2c,
    t1."Range",
    t1.bcr,
    t1.Dataset ID,
    t1.ACC,
    t1.GNC,
    t1."Year",
    t1.Period,
    t1."Week",
    t1.Job_ID,
    SUM(s.Total) AS JOBTOTAL
FROM    
    dbo.TABLE1 t1
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Sales s
       ON t.Job_Id = s.Job_id
WHERE
    t1.ACC='ACCOUNT57' 
    AND t1.Dataset ID=5 
    AND t1.bcr=1 
    AND EXISTS (SELECT *
             FROM
                dbo.TABLE2 t2
             WHERE
                t1.GNC = t2.Contract
                AND t1.Period = t2.FromPeriod
                AND t1."Week" = t2.FromWeek
                AND t1."Year" = t2.FromYear
                AND t2."Range"='Week')
GROUP BY
    t1.Sheet Number,
    t1.ID Number,
    t1.Identification,
    t1."Job Date",
    t1.p2c,
    t1."Range",
    t1.bcr,
    t1.Dataset ID,
    t1.ACC,
    t1.GNC,
    t1."Year",
    t1.Period,
    t1."Week",
    t1.Job_ID
ORDER BY
    t1.Sheet Number
```

You can also do it this way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.Sheet Number,
    t1.ID Number,
    t1.Identification,
    t1."Job Date",
    t1.p2c,
    t1."Range",
    t1.bcr,
    t1.Dataset ID,
    t1.ACC,
    t1.GNC,
    t1."Year",
    t1.Period,
    t1."Week",
    t1.Job_ID,
    s.JOBTOTAL
FROM    
    dbo.TABLE1 t1

    INNER JOIN dbo.TABLE2 t2
    ON t1.GNC = t2.Contract
    AND t1.Period = t2.FromPeriod
    AND t1."Week" = t2.FromWeek
    AND t1."Year" = t2.FromYear
    AND t2."Range"='Week'

    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT
                SUM(s.Total) AS JOBTOTAL
             FROM
                dbo.Sales s
             WHERE
                t.Job_Id = s.Job_id) s
WHERE
    t1.ACC='ACCOUNT57' 
    AND t1.Dataset ID=5 
    AND t1.bcr=1 
ORDER BY
    t1.Sheet Number
```

Comment: Thank you so much - only problem i have now is that the JOBTOTAL sum is bringing back 4 values - 2 are for the correct amount and 2 are the correct amount doubled. 
e.g.
job1 = £10
job1 = £20
job1 = £20
job1 = £10

Comment: table 2 is probably causing more than 1 row to be returned on the table 1 join.  I take it table 1 is a one to table 2 many relationship?

Comment: Yes it brings back a row for each chargable item i wanted the JOBTOTAL field to sum all these up - Its fine though i can solve it outside of SQL by grouping and using minimum() on the field as it either brings in the correct amount or double the correct amount for each job. Thanks for your help!

Comment: SQL is still the good place to solve this.  But are you trying to sum something in Table2 on in sales?  I know sales should be a multiple to 1 relationship with Table1.  I gave you a couple of versions that will work regardless but for future I would put in same sample data from your tables and an expected result that way we can help you find the BEST way to do something instead of trying to make our answers fit with many unknowns.

Comment: table 2 is basically just a table so we can use it as a filter for custom date ranges - table1 has a record of every job and every item in that job and the sales table contains a price record for every item for that job. Im trying to sum every price for every item per job. e.g. bob buys a cheese sandwich- i want to bring back each record with that items price (row1=bread $0.40, row2=cheese $1.00 row3=bread $0.40 row4=butter $0.05) as well as a total price we charged bob in that instance($1.85) but atm i get the price per each row just fine but the JOBTOTAL per row is either correct or doubled

Comment: @Dark the total shouldn't be doubled with the new answers I posted to account for a one to many relatioship in table2!  If they are that means either JobId is doubled in Table1 (unlikely?) or you are really needing a MIN() or MAX() instead of SUM() in Sales because duplicates exist there....

Comment: Thanks for your help - irl check out the table1 tom and check the data for duplicates